# How do I get JQuery post to work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-post

I'm trying to process form data using jQuery post as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#settingsForm').submit( function(){  $('input[type=submit]', this).attr('disabled',   'disabled ');});

function scheck(){
var oldanswer = $("#oldanswer");
var newanswer = $("#newanswer");
var url = "settingsupdate.php";
//This part of the code works fine. Errors are displayed normally
if(oldanswer.val() == ""){
    $('#output').html('Oops you left a field empty. Please fill it').show().fadeOut(6000);
}

else if (newanswer.val() == ""){
    $('#output').html('Oops you left a field empty. Please fill it').show().fadeOut(6000);
}
else{
$.post(url,{oldans: oldanswer.val(),  newans: newanswer.val()},function (data){
    $("#security_check").slideup("fast");//this is a div containing the form
    $("#output").html(data).show().fadeOut(10000);//this div outputs the returned data
    document.settingsForm.oldanswer.value = "";
    document.settingsForm.newanswer.value = "";
        });
    }
}
</script>
```

In the code above, the error check works well. If a field is empty the page will display the appropriate error message. However when both fields aren't empty and the form is submitted, the page just remains static. Nothing is echoed from the php script back to the page.

***settingsupdate.php***

```
if(isset($_POST['newans'])){ 
$oldans = htmlspecialchars($_POST['oldans']);
$newans = htmlspecialchars($_POST['newans']);
echo $newans;
```

}

***the form***

```
<form action="javascript:scheck();"id="settingsForm" name="settingsForm" method="post">
    <input type="text" id="oldanswer" name="oldanswer"/>
    <input type="text" id="newanswer" name="newanswer"/>
    <input type="submit" id="submitset" name="submitset"/>
    </form>
```

I checked print_r($POST) and it returns an empty array. I'm not sure why. Can anyone aid me in getting this code to work properly. Thanks

Comment: Add a .fail(), that may yield some diagnostics

Comment: in your php you have `$_POST['newans']` and in your form `<input type="text" id="newanswer" name="newanswer"/>`, try changing `newans` to `newanswer`

Comment: also its `print_r($_POST);` not `print_r($POST)`

Comment: check your browser console & network tab to check the request

Comment: @ArunPJohny Thanks a bunch for that suggestion. Was able to pinpoint the error from the console. The issue was with the slide function. I incorrectly typed `slideup` instead of `slideUp`.

Comment: @Alexandros Thanks for the input. It's incorrect to use `newanswer` as opposed to `newans` because the variables input into the post array by jQuery are `newans` and `oldans` not `newanswer` and `oldanswer`.

Comment: @ss_millionaire ah yes, iv missed that part